# Testing code to get the average time for the calls

Tags: java

This is my code, I am trying to test what's the average time to make a call to getLocationIp method by passing ipAddress in that. So what I did is that, I am generating some random ipAddress and passing that to getLocationIp and then calculating the time difference. And then putting that to HashMap with there counts. And after wards I am priniting the hash map to see
what's the actual count. So this is the right way to test this? or there is some other way. Becuase in my case I am not sure whether my generateIPAddress method generates random ipAddress everytime. I am also having start_total time before entering the loop and then end_total time after everything gets completed. So on that I can calculate the average time?

```
    long total = 10000;
    long found = 0;
    long found_country = 0;
    long runs = total;
    Map<Long, Long> histgram = new HashMap<Long, Long>();
    try {
        long start_total = System.nanoTime();
        while(runs > 0) {

            String ipAddress = generateIPAddress();

            long start_time = System.nanoTime();

            resp = GeoLocationService.getLocationIp(ipAddress);

            long end_time = System.nanoTime();

            long difference = (end_time - start_time)/1000000;      

            Long count = histgram.get(difference);
            if (count != null) {
                count++;
                histgram.put(Long.valueOf(difference), count);
            } else {
                histgram.put(Long.valueOf(difference), Long.valueOf(1L));
            }

            runs--;

        }
        long end_total = System.nanoTime();

        long finalTotal = (end_total - start_total)/1000000;

        float avg = (float)(finalTotal) / total;



        Set<Long> keys = histgram.keySet();

        for (Long key : keys) {
            Long value = histgram.get(key);
            System.out.println("$$$GEO OPTIMIZE SVC MEASUREMENT$$$, HG data, " + key + ":" + value);
        }
```

This is my generateIpAddress method-

```
private String generateIPAddress() {

        Random r = new Random();

        String s = r.nextInt(256) + "." + r.nextInt(256) + "." + r.nextInt(256) + "." + r.nextInt(256);

        return s;

    }
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this work? Is it broken? If so, what part is broken?

Comment: It is working, just need to make sure what I am doing is the right way to do it. And if there is any better way ?

Comment: why cont u print the generated ipaddress, then you can conform that whether those are generating or not. if you got conformed about that , then you can check average time

Comment: ipAddress are getting generated properly. I just wanted to make sure, any other better way in which we can test this out.

Comment: I am not a benchmarking expert, but it seems you should run it a few times before starting to measure.  JIT stands for Just In Time compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally when you benchmark functions you want to run the multiple times and average the results That gives you are clearer indication of the actual time your program will spend in them, considering that you rarely care about the performance of something only run once.